# How to request HTTP version if HTTPS failed?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, python-requests

I'm doing HEAD requests to a list of sites. Some of them use HTTPS and others just HTTP.

So, I'm using the following code expecting that when a SSLError is raised, a request to the HTTP version should be done. However, it looks like the error is not being caught.

```
for site in top:
    try:
        headers.append(requests.head('https://www.' + site.strip('\n')).headers)
    except ssl.SSLError:
        headers.append(requests.head('http://www.' + site.strip('\n')).headers)
```

For example, if I use Alexa Top 10, when the script reaches `qq.com` (top 9), the HTTPS version raises a `requests.exceptions.SSLError: hostname 'www.qq.com' doesn't match either of 'a248.e.akamai.net', '*.akamaized.net', '*.akamaihd-staging.net', '*.akamaihd.net', '*.akamaized-staging.net'`
.

My expected use case is that if such error is raised, it should request instead `http://www.qq.com`.

PS: I don't want to use `verify=False`, I want to request the HTTP version if the HTTPS raises an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are catching the wrong exception. It's not clear from your code what `ssl.SSLError` is, but it's almost certainly not the same as `requests.exceptions.SSLError`.

Try:

```
import requests

for site in top:
try:
    headers.append(requests.head('https://www.' + site.strip('\n')).headers)
except requests.exceptions.SSLError:
    headers.append(requests.head('http://www.' + site.strip('\n')).headers)
```

Comment: ahh,  what a fail xDD Accepting in 6 minutes

Answer (score 2):

> However, it looks like the error is not being caught.

That's correct. And that happens because *your code* doesn't catch it!

```
except ssl.SSLError:
```

doesn't catch what `requests` throws – which very likely is a `requests.exceptions.SSLError`.